# SQL: Choose latest uploaded data

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am seeing duplicates in my data after running my sql query, and have figured out the issue stemming to our data team not updating a table but adding a new row instead. In this instance, I need to use the largest LD_SEQ_NBR to get the latest data.

Given the following table -- ORDERS

```
ID     ORD_NBR      LD_SEQ_NBR
0     130263789        1665
1     130263789        1870
```

What do I need to add to my WHERE clause to make sure I'm taking the rows with the largest LD_SEQ_NBR?

Comment: Edit tags to show database used. Is there really a record with ID 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LD_SEQ_NBR = (SELECT MAX(LD_SEQ_NBR) FROM ORDERS A WHERE A.ORD_NBR = ORDERS.ORD_NBR)
```